# Trouble with 301 redirect when www is not specified in url in some browsers

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I can't seem to find an answer to this specific question so sorry if it's answered.

**Here's the redirect we have in .htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 /product-name /products/product-name/
```

**Problem:**
If the www is left off then the redirect changes the path and no longer works. e.g. if this is entered into the browser window:

```
domain.com/product-name
```

Then the redirect creates this url in the browser window which obviously doesn't go anywhere:

```
www.domain.comproduct-name
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong sorry - I should also mention that we have a non-www redirect at the bottom of the virtual host file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a / after .com in your redirect from non-www to www:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com/
```

Comment: I was about to post this, but was looking up [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) to be sure, as I'm more used to using mod_rewrite for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a trailing `/` in your `Redirect` rule:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com/
```

The [documentation for that directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) states:

> Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

The matched URL-path is `/`, so anything "beyond" that will be appended. In `http://domain.com/product-name`, the part beyond the matched `/` is `product-name`, so appending that to `http://www.domain.com` (without putting a `/` back in) will give you `http://www.domain.comproduct-name`, as you observed.